# Android app crash puzzle

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I've created an Android app that works perfectly on my device. I have sent over the APK to someone, and it worked on his device also.

At one point, he wanted to modify something in the app. So I sent him over the complete source code.

Now he is telling me that the source code does not work for him. It compiles fine, but when it runs it from within Eclipse it crashes.

I am 100% sure I have sent him the correct code, that works fine for me. Apparently there is no reason for the crash.

I asked him to send me the logcat errors and I don't seem to find the problem.

Here it is (part of it):

```
05-06 08:56:10.954: D/dalvikvm(266): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2720K, 13% free 27384K/31239K, paused 40ms, total 42ms
05-06 08:56:11.224: D/dalvikvm(266): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4048K, 21% free 24747K/31239K, paused 35ms, total 37ms
05-06 08:56:11.224: I/dalvikvm-heap(266): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 3785616-byte allocation
05-06 08:56:11.284: D/dalvikvm(266): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 31K, 21% free 24715K/31239K, paused 54ms, total 54ms
05-06 08:56:11.284: E/dalvikvm-heap(266): Out of memory on a 3785616-byte allocation.
05-06 08:56:11.284: I/dalvikvm(266): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
05-06 08:56:11.284: I/dalvikvm(266):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x2bc9b568 self=0x55569be0
05-06 08:56:11.284: I/dalvikvm(266):   | sysTid=266 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=716000068
05-06 08:56:11.284: I/dalvikvm(266):   | schedstat=( 4120000000 11950000000 1161 ) utm=335 stm=77 core=0
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:640)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:620)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at com.android.launcher2.Cling.dispatchDraw(Cling.java:208)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:12717)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13154)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13461)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13342)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2806)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at com.android.launcher2.DragLayer.dispatchDraw(DragLayer.java:743)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13461)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13342)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13340)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13340)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13461)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2183)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawSoftware(ViewRootImpl.java:2258)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2153)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2021)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1832)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-06 08:56:11.294: I/dalvikvm(266):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-06 08:56:11.294: D/AndroidRuntime(266): Shutting down VM
05-06 08:56:11.294: W/dalvikvm(266): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2bc9a300)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:640)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:620)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at com.android.launcher2.Cling.dispatchDraw(Cling.java:208)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:12717)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13154)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13461)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13342)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2806)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at com.android.launcher2.DragLayer.dispatchDraw(DragLayer.java:743)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13461)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13342)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13340)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13340)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13461)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2183)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawSoftware(ViewRootImpl.java:2258)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2153)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2021)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1832)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-06 08:56:11.334: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-06 08:56:11.346: W/ActivityManager(152):   Force finishing activity com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher
05-06 08:56:11.449: E/libEGL(36): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
05-06 08:56:11.449: E/libEGL(36): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
05-06 08:56:11.449: E/libEGL(36): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
05-06 08:56:11.449: E/libEGL(36): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
05-06 08:56:11.449: E/libEGL(36): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
05-06 08:56:11.449: E/libEGL(36): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
05-06 08:56:11.449: E/libEGL(36): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
05-06 08:56:11.449: E/libEGL(36): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
05-06 08:56:11.449: E/libEGL(36): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
05-06 08:56:11.449: E/libEGL(36): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
05-06 08:56:11.449: W/WindowManager(152): Failure taking screenshot for (266x425) to layer 21005
05-06 08:56:11.954: W/ActivityManager(152): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{2c584740 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}
05-06 08:56:11.954: I/ActivityManager(152): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher u=0} from pid 0
05-06 08:56:22.035: W/ActivityManager(152): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{2c57af08 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}
```

Comment: Looks like a bitmap is consuming too much memory. Did he add images?

Comment: OutOfMemoryError.....

Comment: That's the thing: my original source code did not use any images. And he told me he is just trying to compile my source code for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is a pretty  usual one: your app is running out of memory when it's trying to allocate space for a Bitmap you're using.

There are some techniques you can look up at the Google documentation site for Android programmers. For instance [Managing Bitmap Memory](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html).

To avoid the error, this is a pretty good function (again, from Google docs):

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

        // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
        // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
        // requested height and width.
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

 public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

What is does is:

1. Verify the height and width of your Bitmap without actually loading it into memory
2. Adjust the sampling size so it fits into memory but keeps the required dimensions

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase **VM Heap** *memory in AVD* as **64**.

In menu select
**Window** => **Android Virtual Device Manager** => select **avd** which you use => click on **edit** button.

***In old Version of ADT.***

[image]

***In new Version of ADT.***

[image]

When you create new AVD it takes 24 VM Heap as default. but your application need to more memory so, you set it as 64.

Comment: Isn't that a bit problematic? The way I understand the question, it's crashing on an actual device and you can't change the heap's parameters on actual devices, can you? If anything, I would advise him to configure an image on AVD that has the same characteristics of his friends' device so he can see where and how his app is crashing.